# VSTS use of only the "Build & Release" Feature, Notifications for external GitLab Users?

Tags: continuous-integration, azure-devops, gitlab

Hy

When we would like to use VSTS only for the Build & Release Part and connect to GitLab as the external source control system (we use the 5 free user licenses to set up the build and release definitions and do not have additional user licenses):

- Does a User (which does not have an vsts user account/license) who triggers a build through his code-change in the external gitlab, receives for example a build notification mail (with all the information regarding the build/release error), when his build fails?

If this does not work, is the conclusion, that we need a vsts user license for each user in gitlab?

Thanks for your help.

Peter

Answer (score 0):

VSTS can only send the email to the user that started the build if it knows who the user is.

So if you want the build to send the email to the correct person yes, you would need the have a user in VSTS to the build to be assigned to.

Comment: ok, but I still don't understand clearly, even if we create the users in vsts, vsts still does not know which users triggered the build on gitlab right?

Comment: I'm not sure about this part, but I would try to give the user in gitlab the same login name as in VSTS. For example, ins VSTS you have john@sample.com. Create a user as john@sample.com in gitlab and give it a try.

Comment: ok maybe i'll try, but I don't think this will work. Wenn a build is triggered from the external gitlab repo, I see Requested by Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.TFS and not a specific user.

Answer (score 0):

To make sure the 5 users can work between VSTS build/release and GitLab, you just need only **one VSTS account**. Details as below:

1. Email addresses for the 5 users

   You need to know the 5 user's email addresses for following use.
2. Sign up for VSTS account by an email address

   Sign up with an email address and the user will be the VSTS account owner.
3. Add other 4 user's email addresses in the VSTS account

   Now add other 4 users in the VSTS account. You can refer A[dd users to your account.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/accounts/add-account-users-from-user-hub?view=vsts)

   **Note:**  the email addresses in the same domain (such as all of them are Microsoft accounts) can make it easier to add users to a VSTS account. Else you can refer [Add an external user to your VSTS account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/accounts/add-external-user?view=vsts).

To set email notifications, you can specify in Notifications Hub 
(https://account.visualstudio.com/_notifications).

Such as to add a notification to user1 when he queues build fails, you can add a subscription as below:

[image]

And if a build is queued manually, you can also find who queued the build in the build summary page:

[image]